# Every diagonalizable matrix is orthogonally diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, fake-proofs

Hi so I came a across a statement in my book saying that a Matrix is symmetric iff it is orthogonally diagonalizable. Would that not mean every diagonalizable matrix is symmetric? Take a matrix that is diagonalizable, use Gram-Schimdt to make them orthogonal, normalize and now we can orthogonally diagaonalize it, hence it is symmetric. I must be wrong somewhere, so i would appreciate if you could point out my mistake in reasoning.

Comment: Diagonalizing a matrix $A$ amounts to finding a [similarity transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) (a.k.a. basis change) $P^{-1}AP$ which results in a diagonal matrix. However Gram-Schmidts process is not a similarity transform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The eigenspaces of a matrix (with distinct eigenvalues, say) need not be mutually-orthogonal, so generally there's no way to choose an orthonormal eigenbasis. (Gram-Schmidt doesn't preserve eigenspaces.)

Comment: For clarity, I should add that Gram-Schmidt applied to a collection of eigenvectors _in a single eigenspace_ (i.e., having the same eigenvalue) does yield an orthonormal basis of that eigenspace. The assertion "Gram-Schmidt doesn't preserve eigenspaces" refers specifically to non-orthogonal eigenvectors with different eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2):

A matrix $A$ is called **symmetric** if $A=A^T$.

A matrix $A$ is called **diagonalizable** if there exists an invertible matrix $B$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $BAB^{-1}=D$.

A matrix $A$ is called **orthogonally diagonalizable** if there exists an orthogonal matrix $U$ (i.e., $UU^T=I$) and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $UAU^{-1}=D$.

Note that if you "take Gram-Schmidt to make them orthogonal", you replace the original matrix with a different matrix, and the above definitions do not fit any more.

Answer (score 2):

> Would that not mean every diagonalizable matrix is symmetric?

No, but it does meant that every *orthogonally* diagonalizable matrix is symmetric.  For example, the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1&1\\0&0}
$$
is diagonalizable, but not symmetric.  As such, it is not orthogonally diagonalizable.

> Take a matrix that is diagonalizable, use Gram-Schimdt to make them orthogonal, normalize and now we can orthogonally diagaonalize it, hence it is symmetric.

I have no idea what you're describing here, so it's hard to find any "mistake in your reasoning".